# making a jquery toggle div only toggle off when i click a exit button

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

so i am toggleing a div on and off using slidetoggle(); in jquery but everytime that i click anywhere on the screen it just toggles back off [here](http://billischill.ddns.net/fbla) is the site

and here is the code that i am using

**jquery**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      firstLoad();

      $('#a1').live('click', function(event) {
          toggleFoodDiv();
      });

      $('#a2').live('click', function(event) {
          toggleLazerTagDiv();
      });

      function toggleFoodDiv(){
        $('#food-div').slideToggle("fast");
      }
      function toggleLazerTagDiv(){
        $('#lazertag-div').slideToggle("fast");
      }
    });
    //both of those divs use the .information class
```

**css**

```
.information{
z-index: 2;
top:60px;
left:0px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#2c3e50;
opacity: 0.9;
filter: Alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `.live()`? Do you need to use jQuery < 1.7?

Comment: idk what is an alternative for that?

Comment: It was replaced with `.on()` in 1.7. Isn't it in the documentation?

Comment: awesome ill try that out thank you

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt work and i'm using 1.7

Comment: Did you use the correct syntax? `$(document).on("click", "#a1", function...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row-img" id="a1">
    <div id="food-div" class="information" style="display: none;">
    <h2 class="info-h2">We Serve food Too!</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since `#food-div` is *inside* of `#a1`, the entire screen is filled with `#a1` once the `.information` div is visible.

Just pull the `.information` divs out.

```
<div class="row-img" id="a1"></div>
<div id="food-div" class="information" style="display: none;">
    <h2 class="info-h2">We Serve food Too!</h2>
</div>
```